# Laravel Route Group Second Parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I updated my project from laravel 5.5.* to 5.5.43... Before the update everything was ok. But after the update, I see a warning message in `route/web.php`.

[image: laravel route warning]

> It says: Required parameter `$routes` missing.

But everything is working fine. Then when I put an empty string in the second parameter warning message gone.

[image: laravel route warning]

So my question is:

1. What should I put in the required second parameter?
2. If it's required then why everything is working fine? It should be optional.

Comment: Try defining it this way `Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty hard to follow in Laravel.  Your IDE is pulling the group definition from Router instead of RouteRegistrar.

**Inside Router.php:**

```
public function group(array $attributes, $routes)
```

This supports the older style of route group definitions where middleware are defined in attributes and your routes closure would be the 2nd argument.

**Inside RouteRegistrar.php:**

```
public function group($callback)
```

This is the new style where group only accepts the closure.

---

I don't like the fact that they used a condition in __call instead of defining a method for middleware, but when you call Route::middleware, the facade forwards to Router and Router::__call is returning a RouteRegistrar instance because of this line:

```
    if ($method == 'middleware') {
        return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, is_array($parameters[0]) ? $parameters[0] : $parameters);
    }
```